# Convector DB3 to for FoxPro

Tags: sql, sqlite, foxpro

Hello from Russia!

I have a couple of hours looking convector from db3(sqlite) to Foxpro.

Maybe you know this?

Please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [ESF Database Migration Toolkit](http://www.easyfrom.net/), it is a commercial product, but it is worth the money they ask ...

> This toolkit dramatically cuts the effort, cost, and risk of migrating
>   to/from any of the following database formats: Oracle, MySQL, SQL
>   Server, PostgreSQL, IBM DB2, IBM Informix, InterSystems Caché,
>   Teradata, Visual Foxpro, SQLite, FireBird, InterBase, Microsoft
>   Access, Microsoft Excel, Paradox, Lotus, dBase, CSV/Text and transfer
>   any ODBC DSN data source to them.